# In CVS how to find whether i have a commit rights or not without trying to commit

Tags: permissions, cvs, commit

In CVS is there a way to query the permissions for a module to know whether we have commit rights

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CVS doesn't have a way of doing a "dry run" - neither could find a way of checking for commit rights.